# Webpack file-loader is not copying the files & not updating the URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, webpack, angular-material

I'm trying to output all image files through webpack file loader, webpack is ignoring all images. By the way i am importing html files as partials in my angular app.

My webpack setup for images with file-loader

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/vendor.[hash].css');
const extractLESS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/app.[hash].css');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './app/scripts/app.js',
    webui: './app/component/scripts/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    // Absolute output directory
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),

    // Output path from the view of the page
    // Uses webpack-dev-server in development
    publicPath: '/dist',

    // Filename for entry points
    // Only adds hash in build mode
    filename: 'js/[name].[hash].js',

    // Filename for non-entry points
    // Only adds hash in build mode
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[hash].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Webpack Starter Angular - kitconcept',
      template: 'app/index.html',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
      }
    }),
    extractCSS,
    extractLESS
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [

      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: extractLESS.extract({
          use: [{
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "less-loader"
          }],
          // use style-loader in development
          fallback: "style-loader"
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        loader: extractCSS.extract({
          use: [{
            loader: "css-loader"
          }, {
            loader: "less-loader"
          }],
          // use style-loader in development
          fallback: "style-loader"
        })
      },
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader'},
      // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
      //{test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'},
      // helps to load bootstrap's css.
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/octet-stream&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=image/svg+xml&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?limit=1024&name=images/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules", "bower_components", "bower_components/webui", "app/component/"]
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map'
};
```

My main file where i import all the html partials

```
  //importing template 
  import toolbar from '../views/toolbar.html';

  angular
    .module('se-branding', ['ngMaterial',])
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {   
        $stateProvider.state({
          name: 'toolbars',
          url: '/toolbars',
          template: toolbar // passing  imported template for a state
        })
    }])
```

My template file is below

```
<md-icon md-svg-icon="component/images/icons/16px/se_user.svg"></md-icon>
```

i am trying to copy the files from component/images to dist/images and the same should be updated in the html partials. But webpack is rendering the html as same as original file and does not copy the files to dist/images folder.

please help.. i am stuck with issue for almost 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try using url-loader like below instead of file-loader,

```
   { 
           test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, 
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000' 
   },
   {
         test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024'
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your entire webpack configuration

Comment: Updated the webpack entire configuration in the question itself.

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you try replacing last 2 loader rules with above.( Remove mime type info from svg rule ) Can you please try this once

Comment: Thanks @abhishek I tried with your code.But still i am not getting any images updated in the dist folder. I couldn't figure out how url-loader seems to work. Because in the webpack build log It is not doing any transpiling on the images. Can you please explain why by removing mimetype will it work?

Comment: Can you please try the configuration mention in this starter : https://github.com/abhiisheek/angular1-x-webpack-strater. This generates images with prod build.

Comment: @SureshBabu Can you try the webpack configuration in https://github.com/abhiisheek/angular1-x-webpack-strater. For reference I have added a sample image. Download, install packages and run `npm start`